# Custom UIFont is nil

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, fonts, uifont

I am implementing a custom font. Here is my code:

```
    UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName: @"FlipboardFont" size: 41.0];

if (font) {

    NSLog(@"Font non-zero and ready for use!");
    label.font = font;

}
```

All variables are set up properly, and also, I have checked nearly every link on this site. Here also is a list of things I have done:

Added the font name + extension as a key value to the 0 item of "Fonts provided by application" array in plist

Deployment Target build setting doesn't go back any farther than version 3.2.

font is included in build target (in the "Copy Bundle Resources" build phase)

raw value of the key for "Fonts provided by application" is UIAppFonts.

But still, it doesn't work. Obviously, my log is never called. What is there to do?

UPDATED:

Ok, so I have tried kevboh's suggestion. In FontBook, I found that the font is named differently to "Helvetica Neue", and then there was a drop down list with different options, I wanted the condensed bold so I tried:

```
    UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName: @"Helvetica Neue Condensed Bold" size: 41.0];
```

But still no luck :(

Comment: i think that FlipboardFont is not supprted by ios, try UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName: @"ArialMT" size: 41.0];

Comment: Does just "Helvetica Neue" work? Usually the modified-version fonts are separate font files.

Comment: possible duplicate of [UIFont with custom font fails with Nil](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9047230/uifont-with-custom-font-fails-with-nil)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open the font with FontBook and make sure you're using the right name in `fontWithName`:, see here: [UIFont with custom font fails with Nil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9047230/uifont-with-custom-font-fails-with-nil)

Comment: I answered my own question, but you lead me there by mentioning the app FontBook. So Tick!

Answer (score 0):

My problem lies in never installing my font, I did that in Font Book and now I had the option to do that in the .xib file. Everything is good!